# Nginx ERR_CONNECTION_RESET only one domain name

Tags: nginx, web, sites

**Problem**
Other sites work with exactly the same configuration, but one site is different and does not work. Browser outputs ERR_CONNECTION_RESET. Nginx logs *6819 # 0: signal process started*.
If you change server _name to another domain then everything works.
Help someone who came across. Thank you.

**My config nginx:**

```
server {
    server_name  example.com *.example.com;
    listen 80;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    server_name example.com *.example.com;
    listen       443 ssl http2;
    # resolver 8.8.8.8;
    root /usr/share/nginx/sites/example.com/html;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript application/javascript;

    #autoindex on;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
    ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

    location ~ /.well-known {
        allow all;
    }

    error_page  404              /404.html;
    # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:8080
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {                      
    proxy_set_header Host            $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1:8080;
 }}
```

Comment: add the following directive to `events` to get a more detailed log of the error: `debug_connection localhost;`

Comment: I added, but unfortunately nothing has changed in the logs

Comment: The site also does not ping, is it to nginx?

Comment: the directive must be added to the `events` section in the preamble of your `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` file. After that: check the config with `nginx -t`, fix any error signaled or reload the server with `nginx -s reload`, try again to get the log. What you mean by `does not ping`? Are both server and nginx running? Try to set the `error_log info` directive

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem... Proxy server didn't work. Face palm.